# Calculating the variance using the Probability Mass Function (PMF)

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance, covariance

**My Problem**:
The random variables X and Y have the simultaneous probability function p<sub>X,Y</sub>(x, y).

| p<sub>X,Y</sub>(x, y) | X = 0 | X = 1 | X = 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y = 0 | 0.1 (Z = 0) | 0.2 (Z = 1) | 0.2 (Z = 2) |
| Y = 1 | 0.1 (Z = 1) | 0.1 (Z = 2) | 0.3 (Z = 3) |

What is Variance(X+Y) ?

**Answer:**
The answer to this problem should be `Var(X+Y) =  0.96`

**My attempt of solving it:**
It is known that if X and Y are independent, then
Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y)
However, we don't know if they X and Y are independent, thus I will use the following rule:
Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2 CoVar(X,Y)
I think this is tricky, and this is were I get stuck.

**My Question**:
How should I go about to solve this problem.
I am very thankful for any help and/or guidance.

Comment: You could calculate the variance by obtaining the explicit 'density' for $X+Y$ first. You do this by, for every value $z$ that $X+Y$ may take, summing the joint probabilities of all combinations of $x,y$ such that $x+y = z$ (i.e. $\sum_{(x,y): x+y = z} p(x,y)$. From this new function $p(z)$ you can then calculate expected value/variance.

Comment: This is a probability mass function (PMF), not a probability density function (PDF).

Comment: Michael , thanks, changed it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marginal probabilities are given by

$$p_X(x)=\begin{cases}0.2&\text{if }x=0\\0.3&\text{if }x=1\\0.5&\text{if }x=2\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\qquad p_Y(y)=\begin{cases}0.5&\text{if }y=0\text{ or }y=1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

From this it's clear that $X$ and $Y$ are *not* independent, since e.g. $p_{X,Y}(1,0)=0.2$ while $p_X(1)\times p_Y(0)=0.15$. So you have

$$\operatorname{Var}[X+Y]=\operatorname{Var}[X]+\operatorname{Var}[Y]+2\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y]$$

and by definition of variance and covariance,

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[X]&=E\left[(X-E[X])^2\right]\\&=E\left[X^2\right]-E[X]^2\\[1ex]
\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y]&=E\left[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])\right]\\&=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]\end{align}$$

So you need to compute the expectations of $X$, $Y$, and $XY$, along with the second moments of $X$ and $Y$, each of which are trivial. All of them boil down to computing the sum

$$E[f(X,Y)]=\sum_{x,y} f(x,y) p_{X,Y}(x,y)$$

For instance,

$$\begin{align}
E[XY]&=\sum_{\substack{x\in\{0,1,2\}\\y\in\{0,1\}}}xy p_{X,Y}(x,y)\\[1ex]
&=p_{X,Y}(1,1)+2p_{X,Y}(2,1)\\
&=0.1+2\times0.2\\
&=0.5
\end{align}$$

Comment: how did you get the marginal probabilites?:)

Comment: e.g.$$p_X(x)=\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}}p_{X,Y}(x,y)$$which follows from the law of total probability

Answer (score 1):

Don't over complicate it.  You have a small table.  You can evaluate the probability for all four values of $X+Y$.

| p<sub>X,Y</sub>(x, y) | X = 0 | X = 1 | X = 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y = 0 | 0.1 (X+Y=0) | 0.2 (X+Y=1) | 0.2 (X+Y=2) |
| Y = 1 | 0.1 (X+Y=1) | 0.1 (X+Y=2) | 0.3 (X+Y=3) |

$\qquad\mathsf p_{X+Y}(z)=\begin{cases} 0.1 &:& z=0\\ 0.3 & : & z\in\{1,2,3\}\\0&:& z\textsf{ is otherwise}\end{cases}$

So...

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(X+Y) &= \mathsf E((X+Y)^2)-\mathsf E^2(X+Y)\\ &=0.3(1^2+2^2+3^2) -(0.3(1+2+3))^2\\&~~\vdots\\&=0.96\end{align}$